# Checking for jQuery Plugin Dependencies before appending script to body

Tags: jquery, plugins, magnific-popup

I am developing a jQuery plugin which uses another plugin - magnific popup (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/).

So when I initialize my plugin I need to search the DOM for any magnific scripts (css or js) in case the user already has this plugin in use. If I don't find it then I append the magnific css to the head tag and the js file after the jQuery script. All fairly straight forward. But what I am wondering is if this is the best way to do this?

I can foresee issues such as detecting an older or modified version of the magnific script which may not work with my plugin. Or instances of magnific used for my plugin conflicting with the users magnific instances.

So potentially this could be quite troublesome. But other than developing my own separate lightbox similar to magnific for my plugin (which I don't want to do) I can't see any other way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your plugin is loaded **after** the user has added the dependency plugin you canm do in your plugin this (pseudo-code):

```
if ('function' === typeof jQuery.fn.magnific) // or whatever the plugin is called
{
// plugin is already loaded
}
else
{
// plugin NOT loaded
}
```

For css you can do a dom search in the stylesheets loaded in the head, provided you know the css url of the depednency plugin (or even a part of it)

for example (pseudo-code, not tested):

```
var isCSSLoaded = $('head').children('link').filter(function(){ return /magnific.css$/.test(this.href); }).length > 0;
```